# No results from Partcover with MSTest

Tags: c#, mstest, code-coverage, partcover

I am trying to get to grips with Partcover for possible integration with a build machine.

I am running Partcover in the command line with the following command:

```
PartCover.exe --settings settings.xml --output results.xml
```

My settings.xml was generated automatically using Partcover.Browser, and looks as follows:

```
<PartCoverSettings>
    <Target>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe</Target>
    <TargetWorkDir>S:\Work\Solution\</TargetWorkDir>
    <TargetArgs>/testcontainer:"TestProject\bin\release\TestProject.dll"</TargetArgs>
    <LogLevel>4</LogLevel>
    <Rule>+[*]*</Rule>
</PartCoverSettings>
```

`S:\Work\Solution` is the root directory of the solution.

When I run this in the command line the tests all run and pass, but nothing happens after `Test Settings: Default Test Settings` is displayed in the command line. No `results.xml` file is created and I can see no evidence of any sort of code coverage analysis.

Is it something simple I'm missing in the settings file? Or is this a more complicated problem?

Edit: Using Partcover version 2.2.36423

Comment: I recommend you use the latest version of PartCover at https://github.com/sawilde/partcover.net4 as that has .NET4 support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments I suspect you are using a very old version of partcover which does not have .NET4 support.

In addition you will find that using the /noisolation switch would be useful should just upgrading to the latest version not work.

You may also find that [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) will work better than [PartCover](https://github.com/sawilde/partcover.net4) as it has 32 and 64 bit support as well as supporting .NET2 and .NET4 - and copes much better with target processes that spin off more processes to do the actual testing.